# Plotting with pandas .plot() method

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I've set the pyplot rcParams as below:

```
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.left']=False
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.top']=False
plt.rcParams['axes.spines.right']=False
plt.rcParams['axes.grid.axis'] = 'y'
```

[image]

And I'm using the pandas.dataframe.plot method because it's quick and convenient. However, the parameters set above are not applied to the graph? It still shows the spines and grids? what am i missing?

Comment: I replicated using random data and the same configuration and it seems to be working for me, can you show the data and the command used in pandas?